# Export data from SQL Server on update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I need to export data from SQL Server when a specific column is updated and wonder if there is some recommended way to do this?

I have a table with an column 'Activated', when this value is changed to true an export should be trigged.

I soppose I need a trigger that reacts on changes in the 'Activated'. And my two options at present is to call the webservice directly from the trigger or let the trigger insert data in a table that my one service reads from and calls the extern service.
Is any of this ideas preferable or is there any other better solution?

Comment: You shouldn't do *anything* in a trigger that depends on any resources external to the database. You presumably *wouldn't* want the update to have to wait for 5 minutes, or fail, if there are issues talking to the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check out the SQL Server Service Broker - it can be used to trigger external actions on changes to the data.

one implementation (which I have not used) can be found here: http://lab.arc90.com/2009/02/05/sqlwatcher-ad-hoc-database-change-monitoring/

Comment: Service Broker was what I needed, SQLWatcher seems nice for monitoring a database but doesn't fit my needs this time

Answer (score 0):

If you have infrequent changes in data (for example classified values), you can use [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) + [SQLDependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191254%28v=sql.105%29) class. Behaind the scene its also uses Service Broker @paul mentioned.

For example, you can have table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    MyTableID INT not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    SomeText nvarchar(50)
)
```

And SQL code (user rights are discussed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12862/Minimum-Database-Permissions-Required-for-SqlDepen)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlDependency.Start("server=<MyServer>;database=<MyDB>;User ID=<user>;Password=<pwd>;Integrated Security=false;");
            Console.WriteLine("Started..");
            get_msg();
            Console.ReadLine();
            SqlDependency.Stop("server=<MyServer>;database=<MyDB>;User ID=<user>;Password=<pwd>;Integrated Security=false;");
        }
        private static void get_msg()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con =
                            new SqlConnection("server=<MyServer>;database=<MyDB>;User ID=<user>;Password=<pwd>;Integrated Security=false;"))
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT MyTableID, SomeText FROM dbo.MyTable ", con);
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(com);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dependency Info = {0}, time: {1}",e.Info, DateTime.Now);
            get_msg();
        }
    }
}
```